# SwiftUI on iOS 12 and below

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I started using `SwiftUI` on Xcode 11, something that bothered me is that when I change the `iOS deployment Target` to iOS 12 or below, none of `SwiftUI` code gets compiled.
Is `SwiftUI` designed to use only on iOS 13 and above?

Comment: very basic search on google and reading out apple's docs for swiftUI, could have answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI is designed for iOS 13 (or higher in the future).
See [SwiftUI Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui), top right column SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the target iOS 13 and Above the Swift UI is available, if you want to provide support for lower versions, you will have to stick to UIKit.

Checkout video here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

Comment: good video but it's for specific apis